# Change Master page button visibility when clicking a button in the child

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a set of aspx pages that use a master page to give the pages a common look and feel ie. header and footer, header has navigation via tab strip and the footer has several buttons that need to be available from each page, ie the ability to save the current page and return to main page or cancel and return to the main page. I have been requested to add the ability to lock and unlock the set of pages which need to be done from any page in the set so I put it in the footer. The tricky part is that the pages can be made to be locked from either clicking the button in the footer or changing the status on the one of the pages. I have it locking when the status gets changed, however I have an issue attempting to get it to hide the master page lock button and unhide the unlock button.

I have tried changing it via the code behind(C#) and via javascript with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FindControl` in the child to find the Button on the Master Page.

```
protected void ButtonInChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = this.Master.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
    button.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar with no luck:

PermitDetails myMasterPage = Page.Master as PermitDetails;
myMasterPage.LockLink.Visible = false;
myMasterPage.UnlockLink.Visible = true;

Comment: What is `PermitDetails`? post some aspx code from the Master Page you want to hide with the button.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement methods in the master page that hide/show your buttons.  These can then be called from the content page depending on the desired logic.

```
namespace MasterPage
{
  void Unlock()
  {
    btnLock.Visible = true;
    btnUnlock.Visible = false;
  }
}

namespace ChildPage
{
  void Unlock()
  {
    (this.Master as MasterPage).Unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I should rephrase, it doesn't change it right after I lock it. if i navigate to another page and come back then it is changed correctly, however I need it to change imediately

Comment: Are you using AJAX on your page?  Is it doing a full post-back?